# Docker image - SkiaSharp : Unable to load DLL 'libSkiaSharp' or one of it's dependenties

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, skiasharp

I'm stucked since I meet the famous "Unable to load DLL 'libSkiaSharp' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)".

I'm running my asp.net core application within a windows docker image.
My project is under .net 6.0

[image]

here is my dockerfile :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
ENV DOTNET_VERSION=5.0.0
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:55003
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 55003

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Medsoft.Hair.PatientService/Medsoft.Hair.PatientService.csproj", "Medsoft.Hair.PatientService/"]
#COPY ["Medsoft.Hair.PatientService/Dependencies/opengl32.dll", "c:/Windows/System32/opengl32.dll"]
#COPY ["Medsoft.Hair.PatientService/Dependencies/glu32.dll", "c:/Windows/System32/glu32.dll"]
RUN dotnet restore "Medsoft.Hair.PatientService/Medsoft.Hair.PatientService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Medsoft.Hair.PatientService"
RUN dotnet build "Medsoft.Hair.PatientService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Medsoft.Hair.PatientService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Medsoft.Hair.PatientService.dll"]
```

Before the first "FROM" of the dockerfile was "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0" but with this my image doens't have any .net sdk installed.
But it doesn't help here.

When I do dotnet --info on the image running, i have this :

> .NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   6.0.400  Commit:
> 7771abd614
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.17763
> OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400\
>
> global.json file:   Not found
>
> Host:   Version:      6.0.8   Architecture: x64   Commit:
> 55fb7ef977
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 6.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>
> Download .NET:   https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
>
> Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info

Looks like I have.net SDK loaded or installed.
Others nugets as pomelo (mysql) are working like this.

Maybe I'm missing some redist to install ?
My skiasharp version is 2.88.1.

[image: I also added skiasharp native windows nuget as recommanded]

What do I miss here? Someone can help ? If more information is needed, I'll provide it !

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe this docker image doesn't support Skia or it is not installed. Try to get another image with a SO.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, you mean a .so file ? 
I never used it atm xD

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693042/dllnotfoundexception-using-skiasharp-1-68-on-linux?

Comment: Have you tried installing `libfontconfig1`? If you do not have rights to install packages, or other reasons not to install , you can simply use `libfontconfig1` [SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies).

Comment: Ok thanks for both of you, I'll try it. I hope it's a duplicate, but I'm on windows images, not linux. 

i'm not sure it will be easy to change from windows images to linux images. 
But I think It could be a good point to do so, no ?
Since I'm in asp net core and microsoft, I prefered windows images in order to have some dependencies pre installed and make the whole deployment easier. but Maybe I'm wrong